# search by retaining the only group for the searched items and hiding others in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I created ng-repeat based on the department group, want to use search filter but when searching for an item then should display only the group for that searched item by hiding other items and other groups as well. 
Right now showing the searched item properly under its group and hiding other items but not other group names.

```js
$scope.users=[
{
"Name":"AA",
"Age":20,
"Department":"Sales",
"Sal":4000
},
{
"Name":"BB",
"Age":25,
"Department":"Accounts",
"Sal":6320
},
{
"Name":"CC",
"Age":34,
"Department":"Sales",
"Sal":8500
},
{
"Name":"DD",
"Age":32,
"Department":"Accounts",
"Sal":3500
},
{
"Name":"EE",
"Age":25,
"Department":"Sales",
"Sal":4900
},
{
"Name":"FF",
"Age":30,
"Department":"Production",
"Sal":4520
}
];


$scope.workers=[
{
"Name":"alpha",
"Age":90,
"Department":"XYX",
"Sal":9999
},
{
"Name":"BETA",
"Age":80,
"Department":"ABC",
"Sal":88888
}];
 $scope.workers=angular.fromJson(jsonData2);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" ng-model="searchOn" ">
<br>

<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in users | groupBy: 'Department' ">
  <div>
    <p>{{ key }}</p>
  </div>
 


  <div ng-repeat="usr in value | filter: searchOn ">
    <div>
      <p>Name: {{usr.Name}} Age: {{usr.Age}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in workers | groupBy: 'Department' ">
  <div>
    <p>{{ key }}</p>
  </div>
 


  <div ng-repeat="wrk in value | filter: searchOn ">
    <div>
      <p>Name: {{wrk.Name}} Age: {{wrk.Age}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

the below is the $scope.users

Name Age Department Sal
AA 20 Sales  4000
BB 25 Accounts 6320
CC 34 Sales  8500
DD 32 Accounts 3500
EE 25 Sales  4900
FF 30 Production 4520


and the end result I want something like below

Department
 
 Sales:  AA 20 Sales  4000
         CC 34 Sales  8500
         EE 25 Sales  4900

 Accounts: BB 25 Accounts 6320
        DD 32 Accounts 3500

 Production: FF 30 Production 4520
```

Comment: Please include more code in details with values and javascript controller

Comment: we will be happy to help if you provide  $scope.users as json kind instead this

Comment: just updated the $scope.users as json data.

Comment: **SaE**, Did you get me update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a temporary variable to store your filtered `users`.
like :

```
ng-repeat="usr in filteredArray = (value | filter: searchOn)"
```

and bind the length of filter data to `ng-if`. like :

```
 <p ng-if="filteredArray.length > 0" ng-bind="key"></p>
```

See this [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/28677/)

**Updated Fiddel** [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/28687/) for updated question.

Comment: your jsfiddle for one $scope.users is working quite fine, but I do have one more $scope.workers variable with some json so on clicking of show-workers button i switch to workers and on clicking of show-users I switch to users but when having two scope variables and searching then its searching fine but displaying other scope.workers data below the result(actually only its group names). Updating my question with another scope.worker variable.

Comment: **Anoop**, in your updated jsfiddle I have this br lines and while searching for an item(if searching accounts or production item) then its searching the item properly but then its adding these br above the searched item which I want to remove. Here is the sample. **<div>Name: {{usr.Name}} Age: {{usr.Age}} Salary: {{usr.Sal}}</div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>**

Comment: I just added these lines to separate the 2 data for UI perspective, you can remove them ofcourse. and moreover you should have your own `html template` in which you need to bind data of `ng-repeat`, Your original problem is solved with temporary filtered array and if you have any problem in `html` template then please ask separate question and close this thread..

Comment: **Anoop**, this line I used and its working really good. <br ng-if="!usr.length==0" />. Thanks alot for your jsfiddle it works awesome.